# Why timer_create spawns thread if we used sigev_notify as SIGEV_THREAD

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, linux-kernel

As per timer_create function if we used SIGEV_THREAD as sigev_notify then each time expiry new thread will create. But why timer_create function spawns new thread, below my example,

```
int main(){

  printf ("My process ID %d", getpid ());

  int status = 0;

  timer_t timer_id;

  memset (&timer_id, 0, sizeof (timer_t));

  int j = 10;

  struct itimerspec ts;

  struct sigevent se;

  se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;

  se.sigev_value.sival_int = j;

  se.sigev_notify_function = timer_thread;

  ts.it_value.tv_sec = 3;

  ts.it_interval.tv_sec =0;

  status = timer_create (CLOCK_REALTIME, &se, &timer_id);

  printf ("timer_id is %ld\n",(long int)timer_id);

  assert (!status && "Create timer");

  status = timer_settime (timer_id, 0, &ts, 0);

  assert (!status && "Set timer");

return 0;

}
```

Number of threads running in this particular process-id is two,

PID  SPID TTY          TIME CMD

9945  9945 pts/20   00:00:18 timer_create

9945  9946 pts/20   00:00:00 timer_create

If we use SIGEV_SIGNAL , timer_create doesn't create thread.

Please any one tell me why thread created (if we are using SIGEV_THREAD) during timer_create function..??

Answer (score 3):

It needs a helper thread to satisfy `SIGEV_THREAD` requirement to invoke the callback from another thread, [`man sigevent`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sigevent.7.html):

> SIGEV_THREAD
>
> Notify the process by invoking `sigev_notify_function` "as if" it were the start function of a new thread. **(Among the implementation possibilities here are that each timer notification could result in the creation of a new thread, or that a single thread is created to receive all notifications.)** The function is invoked with `sigev_value` as its sole argument. If `sigev_notify_attributes` is not `NULL`, it should point to a `pthread_attr_t` structure that defines attributes for the new thread (see `pthread_attr_init`(3)).

If you look into glibc implementation of [`timer_create`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_create.c;h=a49a546e717c01bf67423854d51e5acd21dddadc;hb=HEAD#l100) you may notice it creates one thread to handle all timers with `SIGEV_THREAD` option:

```
/* Create the helper thread.  */
pthread_once (&__helper_once, __start_helper_thread);
```